# Twig call function when variable doesn't exists

Tags: php, methods, twig, magic-methods

Is it possible in twig to register a callback which is called, when a template variable doesn't exists to return a default value or something like a magic __get method?

Comment: Would you want that for any missing variable, or only under certain conditions? You could write a macro and use that to test the value and display a default value if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Perfect would be for any missing variable. It's important that I don't modify the original twig code.

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

Answer (score 1):

*Extract from :* http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html

---

```
{{ var|default('var is not defined') }}

{{ var.foo|default('foo item on var is not defined') }}

{{ var['foo']|default('foo item on var is not defined') }}

{{ ''|default('passed var is empty')  }}
```

---

Imagine you've got a `twig extension` with `country` `filter` :

```
 {{ myNullVariable|default('FR'|country) }}
```

Comment: Hmm this is not what I need. Something like a plugin for twig, a hook or event which gets called when a variable doesn't exists and I can return a default value or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `Twig_Template`, and override the function `getContext`. The default behaviour of this function is to throw an exception when a variable isn't set, and it should only raise an error, not end the rendering process.

Note that I use an old Twig version, so this may have change. The function to call so that there's an exception is `$twig->enableStrictVariables();`

Comment: For anyone reading this -- For some reason, getContext() is written as final.  Twig has serious problems with overriding default behavior for special cases.

This would be very simple, literally changing the "`return;`" to "`return 'something';`" after the array_key_exists() check, but because the author marked the class as final, instead of specifying the 'base_template_class' in the config, you'd need to fork it / modify the source directly.